# Wordpress filtering through custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, custom-taxonomy

I was wondering if someone could help me out, I need to create a search filter to filter through the posts on my clients page that works like the one on [this site here](http://www.permco.com/)

I have set up custom taxonomies for all the posts but need to be able to filter through them like that site does.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as I have no idea where to start on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get a list of terms on each taxonomi [use this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
2. Put your selects inside a form
3. Create a jquery function using onchange, so each time the user select an option you redirect to the current term page. [you can use this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)
4. If you want to style the selection list, I [suggest this](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)

Comment: thanks for your help, I think this will really work. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is create a form in `searchform.php`, some of the fields are going to be `selects`from the terms in that taxonomy, you can list the term in a taxonomy with this function `wp_dropdown_categories`.

In the `search.php` file you have to create a custom query (WP_Query), using the parameters you got in the form. (if you are using taxonomies you can use this function to get the value `get_query_var`)

And you call the form in your template with `get_search_form`.